# Concat 2 Dataframes off of 2 columns of matching data but keep the remaining

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen how you can merge 2 DFs off of 2 column IDs but it appears as though this creates duplicate values for every iteration. I want to know how to match up 2 columns as if it was a concatenated ID.

```
df1
1    3    12
1    4    14

df2
1    3    12
1    4    12

Desired Output
id1  id2  df1   df2
1    3    12    12
1    4    14    12
```

Basically I want to have returned where they inner join off of the 2 columns but to also include the different data after it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together this quick code to re-produce your DataFrame examples and to produce the desired output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1],'id2':[3,4],'value1':[12,14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1],'id2':[3,4],'value2':[12,12]})
new_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['id1','id2'])
```

This merge command produces an inner join (i.e., uses intersection of keys from both frames) together on the `id1` and `id2` columns found in both frames.

Comment: Hi, I agree this works. Do you have any thoughts as to why when I do this with a larger dataset it doesn't seem to hold true? Does every column have to match off perfectly?

Comment: all of the types are string and contain the same data. Would white space cause a problem?

Comment: confirmed white space was my problem but you answered the true question, thanks. This can also probably be marked as a dup question